# Laravel5.8: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. issue

Tags: php, laravel, forms, laravel-5, post

I am setting user profile update section. 
But when I went to profile create page, I got a following **error**.

> The `GET` method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   `POST`.

I tried `php artisan route:clear` and checked everything. 
But I couldn't solve this issue, so I am glad if someone helps me out.

**`web.php`**

```
Route::get('user/profile','UserController@index')->name('profile.index');
Route::POST('user/profile/create', 'UserController@store')->name('profile.create');
```

**`create.blade.php`**

```
<form action="{{route('profile.create')}}" method="POST">@csrf

                    <ul class="information">
                        <li>Name :<br>
                            <input type="text" class="name" name="name">
                        </li><br>
                        <li>Gender :<br>
                            <div class="gender">
                                <select name="gender" id="" name="gender">
                                    <option class="option" value="" selected="selected">Select Gender</option>
                                    <option value="" >Male</option> 
                                    <option value="United States" class="selected">Female</option> 
                                    <option value="United Kingdom">Any</option> 
                                </select>       
                            </div>
                        </li>   
                        <li>Country :<br>
                            <div class="country">
                                <select name="country" id="" name="country">
                                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option> 
                                    <option value="United States" class="selected">United States</option> 
                                    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option> 
                                </select>
                            </div>    
                        </li><br>
                        <li>Birthday :<br>
                            <input type="text" class="birthday" id="bod" name="bod">
                        </li><br>
                        <li>User Description :<br>
                            <textarea name="description" id="" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea></li>
                    </ul>
                    <button type="submit" class="saveBtn">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**profile table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('gender');
            $table->string('country');
            $table->string('bod');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**`UserController.php`**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('profile.index');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;


        Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update([
            'name'=>request('name'),
            'gender'=>request('gender'),
            'country'=>request('country'),
            'bod'=>request('bod'),
            'description'=>request('description')
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.index');

    }
}
```

Comment: is there a blade called `index.blade.php` inside profile folder?

Comment: @GayanS.Muthukumarana Yes I have.

Comment: 'user/profile/create'のcreate部分を消してみて貰ってもいいですか？

Comment: can you test the 'user/profile/create' via postman? is it able to get the posted data?

Comment: user/profileのみになるとprofileの確認画面にはいけますが、編集ができなくなってしまいます。。。

Comment: Did you get this error after submitting the form?

Comment: No, before submitting. When I jump to http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/profile/create I get this error.

Comment: then you're not posting any data?

Comment: @IlhamSyahruRamadhan Sorry, I am not using any api, so currently, I cannot test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look you are using only two routes. One is for index and one is for storing. Where is the route that goes to the create page?? Add that route and controller method.

```
Route::get('user/profile','UserController@index')->name('profile.index');
Route::get('user/profile/create', 'UserController@create')->name('profile.create');
Route::post('user/profile/store', 'UserController@store')->name('profile.store');
```

Controller

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('profile.index');
    }

    public function create() {
        return view('profile.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;


        Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update([
            'name'=>request('name'),
            'gender'=>request('gender'),
            'country'=>request('country'),
            'bod'=>request('bod'),
            'description'=>request('description')
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.index');

    }
}
```

Form

```
<form action="{{route('profile.store')}}" method="POST">
```

And your create profile button

```
<a href="{{ route('profile.crate') }}"><button>Create Profile</button></a>
```

Comment: what do you mean?? @su3158

Comment: Thank you for editing because my answer was not enough

Comment: Thank you guys, it makes sense. I finally could make it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not combine validation and save, check separately and use fill () for save

**UserController.php**

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'gender' => 'required',
    'country' => 'required',
    'bod'=>'required',
    'description'=>'required',
]);

Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->fill([
        'name'=>'name',
        'gender'=>'gender',
        'country'=>'country',
        'bod'=>'bod',
        'description'=>'description',
    ])->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried

> php artisan route:clear

and solved this issue.